# How to place a function inside a __construct() in PHP

Tags: php, function, object, construct

I would like to create an object, but i'm a beginner at OOP, tried the code below and it returns the error code:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/acosor/work/bpideeas/branches/testing/clasa/clasa.php on line 25**

Basically I would want to insert a function inside a construct, can't really wrap my head around how to do it.

```
<?php

    $clasa = array(
        'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
        'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
        'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
    );

    $obj = new stdClass();
    foreach ($clasa as $key => $value) {
        $obj -> $key = $value;
    }

    class Clasa {
        function filtru($x, $a, $b) {
            foreach($x as $elev => $arr) {
                if($arr[$a] == $b) {
                    echo $arr['nume'].' '.$arr['prenume'].' '.$arr['varsta'].'<br/>';
                }//if end
            }//foreach end
        }//function end

        public function __construct(filtru($x, $a, $b)) {
            $this -> lista = $x;
            $this -> cheie = $a;
            $this -> valori = $b;
        }
    }//class end

    $z = new Clasa($clasa, 'sex', 'm');

    echo $z;

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because error message clearly explains the source of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include functions inside methods in OOP normally (_construct is a method, all functions are called methods in php OOP and variables in the class' root level are properties)

Instead you create another method and call it from one of it's brother methods:

```
Class Clasa{
    public function filtru($x, $a, $b) {
        foreach($x as $elev => $arr) {
            if($arr[$a] == $b) {
                echo $arr['nume'].' '.$arr['prenume'].' '.$arr['varsta'].'<br/>';
            }//if end
        }//foreach end
    }//function end

    public function __construct($x, $a, $b) {
        $this->filtru($x, $a, $b); // this calls the filtru method
        $this -> lista = $x;
        $this -> cheie = $a;
        $this -> valori = $b;
    }   
}
```

"`$this`" is used to reference current instance's methods or properties, I see you already used it to set some properties, so you can use it to call other methods in the instance as well.

Check encapsulation on google to see what are the differences when you declare these Methods public/private/protected

---

**Edit: how to echo $z as per OP's request**

You can't echo `$z` cos `$z` is not like the variable's you've seen before, it's holding an **Instance** of the **Class Clasa**, that's why you can't echo it, you normally can only echo single values like Strings Integers etc... For example you will get an error if you try to echo an array as well.

What do we do then? You could echo the properties, like `echo $z->lista`. But this is considered a bad practice, look around Stackoverflow a bit for a detailed explanation. Instead let's build a method to output the info you want, and an alternative, a method that returns the values and you can echo them from the outside or do whatever you want.

Class Clasa{
    ... //previous code

```
public function showResults(){
    echo $this->lista.", ";
    echo $this->cheie.", ";
    echo $this->valori;
}

public function returnResults(){
    return "$this->lista, $this->cheie, $this->valori";
}
```

}

So you now could do:

```
$z->showResults(); // this will automatically echo the results because there are echoes in the method;
echo $z->returnResults();//that method will return the string, so you can echo it or do whatever you want with it
```

Comment: Yes, I did this, it outputs the correct data and below it says:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Clasa could not be converted to string in /home/acosor/work/bpideeas/branches/testing/clasa/clasa.php on line 35
Line 35 = echo $z which is $z = new Clasa($clasa, 'sex', 'm');

Comment: How do i echo this now? it doesn't really work with echo $z simple.

Comment: check my edit to see how to echo it

Answer (score 1):

Don't do

```
public function __construct(filtru($x, $a, $b))
```

but use

```
public function __construct($x, $a, $b)
```

instead.

Comment: I would like to be more helpful, but I don't know what you try to acomplish by `public function __construct(filtru($x, $a, $b))`.

Comment: You could say that a function invocation is not allowed in a parameter list.

Comment: And even if it syntactically where allowed, I cannot think of any reasonable semantics to attach to such a construct.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 public function __construct(filtru($x, $a, $b))
```

with

```
 public function __construct($x, $a, $b)
```

and

replace

```
$z = new Clasa($clasa, 'sex', 'm');
echo $z;
```

with

```
$z = new Clasa($clasa, 'sex', 'm');
echo $z->filtru($clasa, 'sex', 'm');
```

Comment: This will output the content twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `filtru()` in constructor, try

```
public function __construct($x, $a, $b){
  $this->filtru($x, $a, $b); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this..?

```
public function __construct($x,$a,$b) {
            filtru($x, $a, $b);
            $this -> lista = $x;
            $this -> cheie = $a;
            $this -> valori = $b;
        }
```

Comment: How do I echo this now? echo $z; doesn't really cut it.